# How does ASP.NET Core know that cookie is valid in cookie authentication?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, session-cookies

I'm trying to understand cookie authentication, particularly for ASP.NET Core. As I understand, how cookie authentication generally works is that a session id is stored on the server side as well as client-side. When making a request, the session id is sent and this is checked against the one in server-side.

I tried cookie authentication middleware in ASP.NET Core using this code this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
   AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
   AutomaticAuthenticate = true
});
```

And in AccountController, upon log in:

```
var myUser = GetUser(email, password);
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, myUser.Name)
};
var props = new AuthenticationProperties
{
   IsPersistent = persistCookie,
   ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1)
};

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), props);
```

I saw that a cookie is in the browser, but where is this stored in the server-side? I thought I needed to store this in the DB to check if valid but it seems its already being stored somewhere because I haven done any DB code yet. Also, how does ASP.NET Core know that the passed cookie is valid?

Comment: Cookies aren't stored on the server at all. Server just decode what the browser sends.

Comment: @Bart Calixto: How does the server know that the cookie is valid?

Comment: not trying to be 100% technically correct: cookie is encrypted with a non-public "machine key" only your server knows, when a client send a cookie, the server tries to decode with it's machine key. If it cannot be decoded it will be discarded (aka invalid).

Comment: Well, forgot this was aspnet-core. For aspnet-core instead of machine key, there's a `DataProtection` api that I'm not familiar with that is responsible for that. https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this setup there is nothing stored on the server. The cookie contains the full serialized, encrypted ClaimsPrincipal and AuthenticationProperties.

There is a reference mode that works like you described that can be used if the identities are too large. In that case yes you do need to set up a data store. No default implementations are provided.
https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/5b29bced0d2f1cfc78843bcd9ec9a828c6fb5fef/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs#L138

Comment: Thanks, so how does the server know the cookie is valid? I'm probably missing something, sorry its not clear to me.

Comment: The cookie auth middleware decrypts it using it's private keys, checks the expiration, etc..

Comment: Does that mean that a hacker can, somehow, create a _fake_ cookie and encrypt it?  Then it can impersonate any user to the backend API.  I can't see how the secret private key can be protected when the whole thing is open-source...

Comment: The private key is generated randomly when you deploy and start the application. The hacker would have to crack the server itself to get the key. At which point impersonation is the least of your worries.